# How to only get 2 out of the 4 parameters returned from a function in python?

Tags: python

My function `getCompMove` returns 4 values:

```
def getCompMove(x,y, pile1, pile2):
    # some calculation, values are changed 
    return x,y, pile1, pile2
```

I need to call it in two different ways

Use all 4 returned results

```
x, y, pile1, pile2 = getCompMove(x,y, pile1, pile2)
```

and using only last two parts of returned tuple:

```
pile1, pile2 = getCompMove(x,y, pile1, pile2)
```

The last line of code will fail at runtime with `Too many values to unpack`

Question: How can I get 2 values out of 4 retuned from a function? Is it possible?

Comment: I found your question interesting (and well answered by Martifn Peiters. To make the question more readable, I edited it and removed unnecessary stuff. Please, review, if it is not changing what you asked for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do several things; the most common are:

- Ignore the first two returned values:

  ```
  _, _, pile1, pile2 = getCompMove(x,y, pile1, pile2)
  ```

  `_` is by convention the name for assignments you plan to ignore.

  In Python 3, a catch-all assignment target can be specified with a `*` prefix:

  ```
  *_, pile1, pile2 = getCompMove(x,y, pile1, pile2)
  ```

  where Python will fit the last two parameters to `pile1` and `pile2`, assigning what is left to `_`.
- Slice the returned tuple:

  ```
  pile1, pile2 = getCompMove(x,y, pile1, pile2)[-2:]
  ```

  where `[-2:]` picks the last two values.

Comment: or `*_, pile1, pile2 = ...` since he (appears to be) using py3.

Comment: @roippi: indeed, I see the `print()` functions. added.